# No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage runtime error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

There are *many* questions on here for this same issue, but not one addresses the root cause or what I'm seeing - and thus the proposed answers aren't helpful.

My app builds with no issues, however, on running, I constantly receieve a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage(Landroid/content/Context;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.ohmd-1/base.apk:classes116.dex)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzc(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
```

I see from other questions that this might be related to support libraries in dependencies having different versions, so I have enforced the single library version(s) by adding the following to my gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
        force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    }
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group.equals('com.android.support')) {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to make a difference. I see in my dependency tree that all the support versions are indeed **28.0.0** as specified in the `resoutionStrategy`, so it looks like that portion is working.

My full gradle file is [here](https://gist.github.com/brspurri/bed2056c3bbad4768c58bb4771bd9e3a).

I have posted my gradle dependencies (`./gradlew app:dependencies`) [here](https://gist.github.com/brspurri/321bf8ad21342596f007f9e2d7d46cb0).

At this point, I'm trying to learn how to properly debug this. I'm at a complete loss. **Does anyone have any idea how to debug this type of error?**

I have - of course - cleaned and invalidated caches **many** times.

**UPDATE**

I have found that the issue is indeed in the `initializeAllApis` section of FirebaseApp.  The specific line is:

```
boolean isDeviceProtectedStorage = ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage(this.applicationContext);
```

`ContextCompat` says its from `com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0`.

So this appears to be referencing the most recent, yet when this line executes, I get the above stacktrace. So while I'm narrowing it down, I still am not sure why this is error is being thrown or how to fix it.

Comment: Go to Build -> Analyze APK and check the `classes116 `. See if you have referenced the right library through there. It could be that you are using a device that has a sdk version if `23` and using the default support library.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be linked to firebase-core. Firebase-core depend on com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0, the minimum android API to use is 24. Make sure that your firebase core lib version match with the API version you're using. Have a look here: [Firebase library dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries)

Comment: According to the dependencies tree given by the OP, all the support versions are  28.0.0, even the one provided by firebase-core

Answer (score 0):

Method [ContextCompat#isDeviceProtectedStorage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#isdeviceprotectedstorage) exists since version `24.1.0`... while that `build.gradle` is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and therefore it is difficult for me to reproduce the issue in my IDE - and so I can only apply common sense, instead of using trial and error, as I'm ordinary used to. If you'd create a `MCVE` with *the least code to reproduce the issue*, I could extend my answer (creating such often results in something, which works); and there seems to be a further `build.gradle`.

Mixing up configurations `compile` and `implementation` should be avoided. these are not just two names for the same, but these are being treated as two configurations. this appears to be the cause for the unexpected behavior. Bending version numbers does not make fixing such an issue easier.

There's this one `compile` dependency (even if it may be supplied at version `28.0.0`):

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

And there's this one `implementation` dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
```

These are rather the [current versions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
```

Refactoring all the `compile` dependencies to `implementation` should result in having both of the dependencies within one and the same configuration, then `ContextCompat` should be known to `FirebaseApp`, as it is supposed to be. Just seen, that the listed `implementation` dependencies have two `unspecified` packages, which does not exactly appear "normal" - and most of the version numbers in general appear outdated. These `resolutionStrategy` configurations should be ditched altogether - and properly fixed, by providing suitable version numbers and then applying exclusion.